# How to power a Raspberry Pi with a flight controller

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, low-power

I am making an autonomous quadcopter and I need Raspberry Pi on board to implement image processing. The issue is that I have a 4in1 ESC which comes with only one UBEC (Universal Battery Elimination Circuit) to power the flight controller, I would need another 5V to power Raspberry Pi.

The flight controller that I am using is an [All in One Pro](http://www.unmannedtech.co.uk/3/post/2013/04/all-in-one-pro-board-setup-with-megapirates-code.html), and the ESC is the [Quattro 4in1 30A ESC](http://www.unmannedtechshop.co.uk/quattro-4in1-30a-esc-quadcopter-esc.html).

As the flight controller is an Arduino board with sensors, I think it should have a 5V output that could power the Raspberry Pi board.

The other option is to get an UBEC and connect the battery to the 4in1 ESC and the UBEC in parallel. Then the ESC goes to the motors and flight controller and the UBEC to the Raspberry Pi board.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's a ubec? Any links to this or the 4in1 thing?

Comment: UBEC: Universal Battery Elimination circuit. It is basically a DC regulator that takes the high voltage of the main battery and converts it to a 5V. For example: http://www.hobbyking.co.uk/hobbyking/store/__16663__HobbyKing_HKU5_5V_5A_UBEC.html

Comment: That hobbyking link says 5V at 5A. Is there some reason you can't send power and ground to BOTH the flight controller and the RasPi?

Comment: I guess it could be possible, the thing is that the speed controller comes with a build in Ubec (3A, 5.3V To power the Flight Controller), may be it does not provide enough current for both FC and Raspberry Pi. If I have to add another Ubec, then I can use one for each

Comment: Just small suggestion, use Pi "B+" model, it uses less energy than older "B" model.

Answer (score 1):

The flight controller has onboard 5V (and 3V3) regulators, so you probably might power it directly via the LiPo pack. That said, the raspberry draws at most [700mA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications), your board *and* your camera *and* no servos (is there a gimbal maybe?) would not exceed your four-in-one regulator BEC maximum current, that is 3A:
[image]

You might have problems only if the Pi is particularly susceptible to the disturbances coming from the switching regulator (I don't think so) and from the motors (that might be).
Just try to use only the BEC you have, your Pi will probably be good.

Comment: Well, I am using a 4s battery (14.8V). I don't think I can connect that directly to the flight controller, or at least I have never seen it before.

Comment: @user41129: When he says "flight controller" I presume he means the ESC since that's the spec he's quoting. Obviously it's not your Ardupilot/MultiWii/KK2/naze board.